# How to write JMeter variables to file on Response Assertion failure

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I have a response assertion under a HTTP Request which checks to see if "Insufficient Access" is displayed when a user logs in. It's a simple text assertion.

On failure only, I want to write the user credentials to a file. I'm trying to do this via JS223 PostProcessor and so far I've only been able to find info on how to write to file using this but I can't find any info on how to check the Response Assertion first

```
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\Loadtest\\log.txt",true); //Create New file with name "subid"
    
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    
    // Need logic to check if response has failed and then do below steps
    if (assertionhasfailed)
    {
        out.write(vars.get("account"));
        out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));//insert new line
    }
    
    out.close();
    fstream.close();
```

EDIT

I resolved this issue by using a JS223 Assertion instead:

```
Boolean result = prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains("Insufficient privileges")

FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\Loadtest\\log.txt",true); //Create New file with name "subid"

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

if (result)
{
    out.write(vars.get("account"));//write value of variable 1
    out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));//insert new line
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
        AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("User has insufficient privileges");
}

out.close();
fstream.close();
```

Question now is whether this is the best way of doing this? I ask because I notice when running the test there is a noticeable delay when it processes the assertion. This might skew performance metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JMeter Test Elements [execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder):

> 0. Configuration elements
> 1. Pre-Processors
> 2. Timers
> 3. Sampler
> 4. **Post-Processors** (unless SampleResult is null)
> 5. **Assertions** (unless SampleResult is null)
> 6. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)

Post-Processor is executed **before** the assertion therefore you don't have access to the actual status of the Sampler.

You need to switch to the [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener), this way you will be able to check whether the sampler is successful or not as follows:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    //your code here
}
```

where `prev` stands for the **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Answer (score 1):

In idiomatic Groovy your code would look like:

```
new File("C:\\Loadtest\\log.txt").withWriter{ out ->
  boolean result = prev.responseDataAsString.contains 'Insufficient privileges'

  if (result) {
    out.println vars.account
    AssertionResult.failure = true
    AssertionResult.failureMessage = 'User has insufficient privileges'
  }
}
```